# Full project folder path necessary to access Assets in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-assets

**EDIT 1**

In VS for Mac it actually works as intended. The described behaviour only occurs in Rider 2022.2.2 for me.

**Original Question**

In my Xamarin Android project I have a folder "Assets" including an asset file "certificate.crt". The build action of the file is set to AndroidAsset. To be able to access the asset with the asset manager I have to specify the full file path.

```
var assetManager = Android.App.Application.Context.Assets;
using (var certStream = assetManager.Open("Users/myuser/Documents/Projects/MyProject/MyProject.Android/Assets/certificate.crt"))
{
    // use the certStream
}
```

I found the file path by renaming the .apk to .zip and extracting the files then. So the .apk included an "Assets" folder and in there were all the folders specified above. But what I obviously want is to just pass the filename to the assets manager.

```
assetManager.Open("certificate.crt")
```

How do I achieve that?

Comment: Something is wrong.  An asset isn’t a file and should require a path.  I’d try deleting and readding the asset

Comment: I meant “should NOT require a path”

Comment: @Jason Deleting and readding did not solve it, at least not for Rider. In VS for Mac it actually works. There I don't need the full path. Also when publishing it from Rider, the assets are placed in that folder structure. In VS when publishing or debugging, the assets are accessible under its "filename".

Comment: nowhere does your question mention that you're using Rider.  It sounds like this is a Rider bug.

Comment: I just found out that it works for VS. I will add that to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems to be a bug in Rider for Mac. VS for Mac works as expected.